# Repeated measures ordinal data analysis SPSS

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, ordinal-data

I'm looking to run an analysis using ordinal data with a repeated measures design, and could do with some advice on how to do so.

I'm looking at whether or not extra curricular activity changes after starting university, and this is measured on a Likert scale for both before and after starting university. So I've collected scores of how often participants engaged in extra curricular activity (never, hardly ever, occasionally, often, very often), for before and after university.

Additionally, I'm interested in seeing whether any changes in extra curricular activity may be a result of gender, so have got gender data (Male/female) for each participant.

I'm not really familiar with ordinal data analysis, so could do with some advice (I know my way around SPSS) about how to analyse this data. I was also wondering whether its possible to transform the data from the Likert scale to say scores of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (corresponding to never-very often) and then run analysis using this as a continuous scale instead of ordinal data.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.